# Checkout Progress box returning empty checkout.accordion.openSection('')

Tags: magento

The "Change" links in the right column progress box no longer work on my site.  Upon debugging, I'm noticing that the AJAX call is returning markup that has an empty checkout.accordion.openSection() call

```
 <dt class="complete">
    Shipping Address <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#payment" onclick="checkout.accordion.openSection('');return false;">Change</a>
 </dt>
```

How is this possible?  I haven't edited progress.phtml in my theme so its the base version.  And looking at the base version it appears to be hard-coded.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's the code in the progress.phtml file for the above markup:

```
    <dt class="complete">
        <?php echo $this->__('Shipping Address') ?> <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#payment" onclick="checkout.accordion.openSection('opc-shipping');return false;"><?php echo $this->__('Change') ?></a>
    </dt>
```

It's basically hard coded, right?  How can this then come through as empty?

Comment: turn on error reporting see what controllers gets called and debug

Comment: It's calling frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml just as expected.  There is the order attribute wedged in at the bottom of each step, but that doesn't affect the markup of the <dt> above.

Answer (score 2):

I found this bug today.  For me it was connected with the Amasty "Order Attributes" extension.  Setting `System->Configuration->Amasty Extensions->Order Attributes` page's "Display attribute values in the progress sidebar" to "No" corrects the issue.

The root cause is the regexes in `code/local/Amasty/Orderattr/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Progress.php`.  The opening capturing parens are in the wrong place:

Wrong (orig):

```
$html = preg_replace('@opc-billing(.*?)<\/dd>@s', '$1'.$this->_getOrderAttributesHtml(2), $html);
```

Right (note opening parens in regex pattern -- this will fix it if applied to other regexes):

```
$html = preg_replace('@(opc-billing.*?)<\/dd>@s', '$1'.$this->_getOrderAttributesHtml(2), $html);
```